# How do mount config file for the couchDB?

Tags: kubernetes, couchdb, mount

I would like to mount couchdb-config to my CouchDB's deployment.

This is my couchDB yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: couchdb-delp
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: couchdb
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: couchdb
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: couchdb
        image: couchdb:latest
        env:
        - name: COUCHDB_USER
          value: admin
        - name: COUCHDB_PASSWORD
          value: password
        ports:
          - name: couchdb
            containerPort: 5984
        volumeMounts:
        - name: couchdb-config
          mountPath: /opt/couchdb/etc/local.ini
      volumes:
      - name: couchdb-config
        configMap:
          name: couchdb-config
```

This is my couchdb-config

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: couchdb-config
data:
  local.ini: |
    [chttpd]
    enable_cors = true

    [httpd]
    port = 5984

    [couch_peruser]
    enable = true

    [cors]
    origin: "*"
    credentials: true
    methods: GET,PUT,POST,HEAD,DELETE
    headers: accept, authorization, content-type, origin, referer
```

Then I get this error msg ->
[Error msg image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VSSk2.png)

```
Error: failed to create containerd task: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: error during container init: error mounting "/var/lib/kubelet/pods/c2895190-e2cc-4ccf-acb0-a41b65edf510/volumes/kubernetes.io~configmap/couchdb-config" to rootfs at "/opt/couchdb/etc/local.ini": mount /var/lib/kubelet/pods/c2895190-e2cc-4ccf-acb0-a41b65edf510/volumes/kubernetes.io~configmap/couchdb-config:/opt/couchdb/etc/local.ini (via /proc/self/fd/6), flags: 0x5001: not a directory: unknown
```

I also included the subPath before. But i also get the error

Is that any way to mount couchdb config in yaml?

Answer (score 0):

You mount the config map as a folder, but then you reference it as a file.

It does not work that way, [according to the documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#add-configmap-data-to-a-specific-path-in-the-volume).

What you need to do is the following (untested, but you get the picture):

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: couchdb-delp
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: couchdb
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: couchdb
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: couchdb
        image: couchdb:latest
        env:
        - name: COUCHDB_USER
          value: admin
        - name: COUCHDB_PASSWORD
          value: password
        ports:
          - name: couchdb
            containerPort: 5984
        volumeMounts:
        - name: couchdb-config
          mountPath: /opt/couchdb/etc/  # Note the missing filename
      volumes:
      - name: couchdb-config
        configMap:
          name: couchdb-config
          items:
            - key: local.ini   # The name of the key in the ConfigMap
              path: local.ini  # The name of the file when in the filesystem
```

However, this causes a different problem: Since you mount a read-only "filesystem" over `/opt/couchdb/etc` and couchdb operates in `/opt/couchdb/local.d`, you would need to mount another volume to this mount point `/opt/couchdb/local.d`.

The suggested solution as per the [image's documentation](https://hub.docker.com/_/couchdb/) is to create a custom docker image which is easy enough:

```
FROM couchdb

COPY local.ini /opt/couchdb/etc/
```

Another solution is what the [official Helm chart of couchDB](https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/couchdb/couchdb) does: An ["init container"](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/) is used to take the configs mounted from config maps and secrets to a temporary path and copies them to the volume provided for `/opt/local/etc`.

In case you only want to deploy CouchDB, I highly recommend using said Helm Chart.